# Does blender still allow partial selection of vertices?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, selection-tools

I can't see anywhere in the latest blender how to partially select vertices, say so that in a move operation, some vertices move less than others by the weight of their selection.

What are the search terms, terminology etc. I am even looking for?

Comment: Not sure if the designated duplicate is the best match here, but it's already happened I guess.  Another search term that you might look into is the use of "vertex groups".  By assigning vertices to vertex groups, you can modulate the effect that a modifier or shape key has on the vertex.

Comment: No, it's proportional editing. Though the linked duplicated topic explains how to use it but not how to turn it on. See [Proportional Editing — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/proportional_editing.html)